# Analysis of Current for infinitesimal time

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-current

Suppose we have a hydrogen atom and electron is revolving in a orbit around the nucleus. We have to find current due to the revolving electron.

Current = ev / 2πr

( e = charge of electron)
( v = velocity of electron)
(r=radius of orbit in which e is moving)

But now if we think deeply and assume that we have a point on orbit and electron is very near to it and electron crosses the point in nearly zero time then we would say that current with respect to this point is very large or say it infinite but that doesn't match the actual value ev/2πr. Now I can't understand what's problem with my assumsion.

Answer (score 1):

Of course your solution is an approximation valid for times long enough that the electron has rotate around the orbit a couple of times - in other words, it is a "mean" value.

We take a description of the orbit in polar coordinates ($\rho$, $\phi$).

Let's take a small small portion of the orbit of angular "thickness" $d\phi$. That "fragment" of orbit has a length $r d\phi$ (where $r$ is the radius of the orbit.

The electron (charge $e$) moves with speed $v$ along the orbit.

The current in the small fragment we choose is $J=0$ when the electron is not there. Let's say at time $0$ it "enters" our fragment of orbit. It will leave it after a time $t_f=rd\phi/v$. So the charge crossing our segment is $e$ in a time $t_f-0=rd\phi/v$ i.e. the current is

$J_1=e/(rd\phi/v)=ev/r d\phi$

Clearly the "smaller" you take $d\phi$ the higher the current. However the electron only spends a fraction $d\phi /2\pi$ of its time in the small fragment and then the current is $0$ so that , if we average over long times, we get

$$J_{m}=0*(2\pi-d\phi)+ev/rd\phi*(d\phi/2\pi)$$

where we are averaging a time period $(2\pi-d\phi)$ with no current and a period  $(d\phi/2\pi)$ with high current. The average turns out to be

$$J_{m}=ev/rd\phi*(d\phi/2\pi)=ev/r2\pi$$ which is your initial answer.

In other words, you are right that in the limit $d\phi \rightarrow 0$ the current becomes "infinite" but only for a very very short time. The current is a "continuous" quantity, averaged over time, is not a very good quantity for "infinitesimal" quantities of charge or time.

Comment: The problem you have with the so called instanteneous velocity is the same for any velocity. If you go in a car with 60miles/h what ist your speed in a second what in 1/1000 of a second what in a moment ? You can only conclude that the velocity is constant all the time so also at any given moment. But this you can only postulate, since measuring velocity needs a real time and space interval.